# sum of recursion relation

Tags: recursion

how should I write the recursion relation using the $\Sigma$ ?

we have $\begin{equation*}
T(n) = \begin{cases}
1 &n=0\\
T(n-1)+n &n>0
\end{cases} \end{equation*}$

so if we suppose we reached the end, the recursion relation is : $T(n)=T(n-k)+(n-(k-1))+(n-(k-2))+...+(n-1)+n$

I'm not sure show to do it since the $k$ was decreasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
T(n) = T(n-1) + n + T(n - 2) + (n-1) + ... + T(2 - 1) + 2 + T(1 - 1) + 1 = \sum_{k = 1}^n {k + T(n-k)}
$$

---

Just for fun, I'll write the closed form (it might be helpful for you), we have:

$$
T(k) - T(k - 1) = k\implies \sum_{k=1}^n {T(k) - T(k - 1)} = \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
Now we have a telescoping series:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n T(k) - \sum_{k=1}^n T(k-1) = \sum_{k=1}^n T(k) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T(k) = T(n)-T(0) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\implies T(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+T(0) \implies \boxed{T(n)= \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1}
$$